# How to divide a page to create widgets?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

1. Before you come to my question section. Could you please run my code snippet and see the results.
2. Once you run my code please click on Expand snippet and see the results.

   -My Question is:

   I need to merge the second box one and second box two. Since both are
   different rows I don't know  how to do it

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
         <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8" />
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
           <title>Document</title>
           <link
             rel="stylesheet"
             href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
             integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
             crossorigin="anonymous"
           />
         </head>
         <body>
           <header>
             <div class="container">
               <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #333; height: 250px;">
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is first box.
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is second box - 1.
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is third box.
                 </div>
               </div>
               <span> </span>
               <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #333; height: 200px;">
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is fourth box.
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is second box - 2.
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is fifth box.
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #333; height: 200px;">
                 <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is sixth box.
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px dotted #333">
                   This is seventh box.
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </header>
         </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Define 'merge' in this context

Comment: When you say `merge`, you expect the layout to change dinamically on some action or do you want just a new static layout that will join those two boxes into one?

Comment: @Ashley Brown :: Could you please explain? How to define merge in this context?

Comment: I couldn't understand you, you want merge these dynamically? If yes I think you couldn't do it with this structure . you should change your structure

Answer (score 0):

I did that in a different way. You can run and see the result in an expanded screen. when it comes to small screen layout gets break. Help me if anyone know how to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="height: 400px;">
          <div class="col">
            <div
              class="mt-2 mb-2"
              style="border:1px dotted #333; height: 200px;"
            >
              widget one
            </div>
            <div class="mb-2" style="border:1px dotted #333; height: 180px;">
              widget two
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-2 mb-2 col-md-6" style="border:1px dotted #333">
            Widget three
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div
              class="mt-2 mb-2"
              style="border:1px dotted #333; height: 200px;"
            >
              widget four
            </div>
            <div class="mb-2" style="border:1px dotted #333; height: 180px;">
              widget five
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height: 300px;">
          <div
            class="ml-3 mt-2 mr-2 mb-2 col-md-6"
            style="border:1px dotted #333"
          >
            Widget - 6
          </div>
          <div class="mr-3 mt-2 mb-2 col" style="border:1px dotted #333">
            Widget - 7
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```